# Gatherv 2D numpy array mpi4py

Tags: python, python-3.x, numpy, mpi4py

I'm learning parallel computing through mpi4py. Since I deal with a large dataset, I need to preallocate the memory at the master process in order to not have memory issues.  That's the reason why I use the  `Scatterv` and `Gatherv` methods. The code proposed has only the scope to allocate the memory without doing any specific operation

```
import numpy as np
from mpi4py import MPI


comm   = MPI.COMM_WORLD
rank   = comm.Get_rank()
nprocs = comm.Get_size()



if rank == 0:
    
    sendbuf = np.random.rand(4,3)
    r, c    = sendbuf.shape

    ave, res = divmod(c, nprocs)
    count = [ave + 1 if p < res else ave for p in range(nprocs)]
    count = np.array(count)
    
    print("count is ", count)

    # displacement: the starting index of each sub-task
    displ = [sum(count[:p]) for p in range(nprocs)]
    displ = np.array(displ)
else:
    sendbuf = None
    # initialize count on worker processes
    count = np.zeros(nprocs, dtype=np.int)
    displ = None
    
    
# broadcast count
comm.Bcast(count, root=0)

# initialize recvbuf on all processes
recvbuf = np.zeros((4,count[rank]))


comm.Scatterv([sendbuf, count, displ, MPI.DOUBLE], recvbuf, root=0) 


a, b     = recvbuf.shape
sendbuf2 = np.random.rand(a,b)
recvbuf2 = np.zeros((4,sum(count)))

comm.Gatherv(sendbuf2, [recvbuf2, count, displ, MPI.DOUBLE], root=0)
```

In the master process, I firstly define a random 2D array (`sendbuf`) of dimensions (4,3). What I want to do is to scatter this matrix to the different process by dividing it in columns (so preserving the number of rows). Then I initialize the `recvbuf` variable in order to receive the chunks of information of `sendbuf`. Then I use the `Scatterv` method to pass the information. I noticed that only the data in the first row are passed correctly. This is not really important, since in the real application the `recvbuf` variable is used only to pre-allocate the memory. At this point I redefine the `recvbuf` variable, and then I try to send back the information to the master node, but the code gives error. I don't really understand what I'm doing wrong in the `Gatherv` part.

I tried to keep the example as simple as possible, so that the code doesn't not do anything specific. What I want to learn is how to correctly scatter and gather 2D numpy array.

Answer (score 0):

What 'error' do you have exactly?

Here's a working version of gatherv with 2D arrays. Keep in mind that the sizes are scaled with the size of the 2D array, as NumPy has arrays row-major in memory

```py
from mpi4py import MPI
import numpy as np

comm_world = MPI.COMM_WORLD
my_rank = comm_world.Get_rank()
num_proc = comm_world.Get_size()

# Parameters for this script
rowlength = 2
sizes = 2*np.ones((num_proc), dtype=np.int32)
sizes[-1] = 1

# Construct some data
data = [np.array((), dtype=np.double) for _ in range(num_proc)]
data[my_rank] = np.array(my_rank+np.random.rand(sizes[my_rank], rowlength), np.double)

# Compute sizes and offsets for Allgatherv
sizes_memory = rowlength*sizes
offsets = np.zeros(num_proc)
offsets[1:] = np.cumsum(sizes_memory)[:-1]

if my_rank == 0:
   print(f"Total size {np.sum(sizes)}")
   print(f"Sizes: {sizes}")
   print(f"Sizes: {sizes_memory}")
   print(f"Offsets: {offsets}")

# Prepare buffer for Allgatherv
data_out = np.empty((np.sum(sizes), rowlength), dtype=np.double)
comm_world.Allgatherv(
   data[my_rank],
   recvbuf=[data_out, sizes_memory.tolist(), offsets.tolist(), MPI.DOUBLE])

if (my_rank == 0):
   print(f"Data_out has shape {data_out.shape}")
   print(data_out[:, 0])
```

Linux OS, MPI: 'mpirun (Open MPI) 4.1.2', MPI4PY: 'mpi4py     3.1.4'